# Removing duplicate values from a dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I am developing an SSRS report with the following dataset (Table-1). I am grouping by Account and Period. My goal is to get the Total Expense and the Budget within a group. Because the Budget data is duplicated per group, I cannot use SUM() function for Budget. How do I remove the duplicates so the new dataset looks like this? (Table-2) Please advice. Thank you for your time.

Table-1

```
ID Account Period  Expense Budget
1  100     201301  20      100
2  100     201301  30      100
3  100     201302  10      150
4  100     201302  40      150
5  200     ...................
```

Table-2

```
ID Account Period  Expense Budget
1  100     201301  20      100
2  100     201301  30      NULL
3  100     201302  10      150
4  100     201302  40      NULL
5  200     ...................
```

Comment: What if you instead summed `Expense` for each group... so that you then consistently showed total expense and total budget for each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make duplicate budgets null try this update command

please check sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e619/11

```
Update table1 
set budget = null
where id in
(
      select aa.id from
        (
          select id,row_number() 
          over(partition by Budget order by Period) as rno
          from table1
        ) aa
     where rno > 1
);

select * from table1;
```

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a windowed function if you have to do that grouping in SQL.  If you can do it in SSRS just add a 'Row Grouping Parent' it would be better.

For SQL I would do this:

```
declare @Temp table ( ID int identity, Account int, period int, expense int, budget int);

insert into @Temp values (100, 201301,  20, 100),(100, 201301,  30, 100),(100, 201302,  10, 150),(100, 201302,  40, 150)

select *
from @Temp

select 
    ID
,   Account
,   Period
,   Expense
,   case when (row_number() over(partition by Budget order by Period) = 1) then Budget end  as Budget-- only shows first occurrence of an order amount ordering by person
from @Temp
```